# How to make sure that only one instance of a thread is running in Python?

Tags: python

I have a program with three threads. I call them like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            t1().start()
        except:
            log.debug('Trouble with t1 synchronizer')
        try:
            t2().start()
        except:
            log.debug('Trouble with t2 synchronizer')
        try:
            t3().start()
        except:
            log.debug('Trouble with t3 synchronizer')
```

I want to keep these 3 threads running all the time. But I also want to make sure that only one instance each of t1, t2 and t3 is running at a time.

**EDIT**

The only solution I can think of is having lock files in each threads. Somthing like

```
if os.path.exists(lockfile):
   EXIT THREAD
f=open(lockfile,'w')
f.write('lock')
f.close()
THREAD_STUFF
os.remove(lockfile)
```

But somehow it does not look like a clean solution to me as the program might have exited because of some reason and the threads may not launch at all.

Comment: You want to keep them all running, but you only want one to be running?

Comment: I want to keep these 3 threads running all the time. But I also want to make sure that only one instance each of t1, t2 and t3 is running at a time.

Comment: I don't understand what an instance of a thread is. All threads are essentially the same, they just run different code.

Comment: @gabe I might be using a wrong terminology. I do not want t1 to be running more than once at a time. Similarly for t2 and t3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct one way to make sure that the threads are only running once each would be with a lock file.

How ever there is another way to check if they are running instead of continuously trying to run them.
By using the following code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        t1().start()
    except:
        log.debug('Trouble with t1 synchronizer')
    try:
        t2().start()
    except:
        log.debug('Trouble with t2 synchronizer')
    try:
        t3().start()
    except:
        log.debug('Trouble with t3 synchronizer')
    Time.sleep(5)
# this sleep allows the threads to start so they will return a True for isAlive()
    while True:
        try:
            if t1().isAlive()==False:
                try:
                    t1().start()
                except:
                    log.debug('Trouble with t1 synchronizer')
            if t2.isAlive()==False:
                try:
                    t2().start()
                except:
                    log.debug('Trouble with t2 synchronizer')
            if t2.isAlive()==False()
               try:
                    t3().start()
                except:
                    log.debug('Trouble with t3 synchronizer')
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know there is a isALive() method. I should be checking the manual better.

Comment: In the meantime, it is better to use .is_alive()
Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive